# Subtle Analysis Problem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, continuity, epsilon-delta

Suppose you have a function $f \colon A \to \mathbf {R} $ and $ (a - \delta', a + \delta') \subseteq A$ for some $\delta' > 0$. Suppose also that $f$ is continuous at $a$. How do you prove that the limit as $x$ approaches $a$ of $f(x) $ equals $f(a)$?

Definition of continuity: for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $x \in A$ and $|x - a| < \delta$ imply $|f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$.

Definition of limit as $x$ approaches $a$ of $f(x)$ equals $f(a)$: For all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $0 < |x - a| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$.

These definitions are pretty similar, but there are some subtleties I can't sort out. One is that $0 < |x - a|$ in the second definition. Another is that $x$ is not required to be in $A$ in the second definition. Also where does $\delta'$ come into play?

I saw a sketch of a solution once that involved taking $\min(\delta, \delta')$ or something similar to that, but I forgot the details and am trying to recapture them.

Comment: The reason why $0 < |x - a|$ is to basically state that we don't care what happens when $x = a$, i.e., it removes the case $x = a$.

Comment: Not explicitly writing $x\in A$ in the second definition doesn't matter: the domain of $f$ is stated to be $A$, so it must be assumed that $x\in A$ is intended if $f(x)$ is referred to. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: The point of considering $\min\{\delta,\delta'\}$ would be this: If one of these two numbers is small enough for one purpose and the other is small enough for another purpose, then whichever one of the two is smaller is small enough for both purposes. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: This is true, but how does it come into use here?